# Request in AJAX doesn't work. Page reloaded

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a page of a product where users can comment. The problem is that the page is reloaded as if there would be no javascript.
Actually the request is HTML (I think)

comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ActionController::Base
  def create
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @comment = Comment.new(params_comment)
    @comment.product = @product
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.js
        format.html { redirect_to @product }
      else
        render :new
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def params_comment
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

In the product show:

```
<% unless @comments.empty? %>
  <h1> Comments </h1>
  <div id="comments">
    <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
      <%= render comment %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= form_for @comment, url: comments_path, method: :create, format: :js, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "product_id", @product.id%>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.text_area :body, :size => "25x1", :placeholder => "Comment here..."%>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit "Comment" %>
<% end %>
```

The _comment.html.erb

```
<p><%= comment.body %></p>
```

And finally the create.js.erb

```
$("#comments").append("<%= escape_javascript(render @comment) %>");
```

When I create a new product, there is no javascript request.
In the console I get:

```
Started POST "/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-19 20:38:29 +0200
Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "product_id"=>"1", "comment"=>{"body"=>"asdas"}, "commit"=>"Comment"}
  Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "comments" ("body", "created_at", "product_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["body", "asdas"], ["created_at", Wed, 19 Feb 2014 18:38:29 UTC +00:00], ["product_id", 1], ["updated_at", Wed, 19 Feb 2014 18:38:29 UTC +00:00]]
   (4.8ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/products/1
Completed 302 Found in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 5.9ms)
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I forgot, in my layout are already included:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

**EDIT 2**

This is the HTML code generated by the form:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/comments" class="new_comment" data-remote="true" id="new_comment" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="create" /></div>
<input id="product_id" name="product_id" type="hidden" value="1" />
<div class="field">
    <textarea cols="25" id="comment_body" name="comment[body]" placeholder="Comment here..." rows="1">
</textarea>
</div>
<input name="commit" type="submit" value="Comment" />
</form>
```

Comment: Can you **View Source** of your product show page and show me the HTML `<form>` tag generated by `form_for`? @dioshari

Comment: I don't see where you are using AJAX at all. Can you show how you are intercepting the submit action and attempting to make an AJAX call isntead?

Comment: @MikeBrant Isn't remote: true taking care of it?

Comment: @franksort I don't know.  Just adding a data attrbitue in and of itself doesn't do anything.  Is there some particular javascript framework you are working with? Are you using jQueryUJS or something like that?

Comment: I have loaded jQuery and jQueryUJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem.

The mistake was that the controllers were inheriting from ActionController::Base instead of ApplicationController, so it was not loading the layout, therefore neither the javascript libraries. 
So I just changed:

```
class CommentsController < ActionController::Base
```

to:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
```

And I was not showing the product controller, but I also had to changed from:

```
class ProductsController < ActionController::Base
```

to:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
```

And it works now!
Thanks all of you who tried to help me!